# Is there a Python equivalent to Ada "and then" and "or else"? (lazy evaluation)

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, ada, short-circuiting, short-circuit-evaluation

With Ada you can use `and then` instead of `and` and `or else` instead of `or`.

In Ada, with the following example, b is only evaluated when necessary (ie if `a` is `true`) when you use the lazy evaluation operators'.

```
if a
    and then b
then
    expr;
end if;
```

Is there a Python equivalent of this?

Comment: You mean `if a and b` ?

Comment: `a and b` <-- `b` won't be evaluated if `a` is falsy. The same way `a or b` <-- `b` won't be evaluated if `a` is truthy

Comment: Python `and` is already the equivalent of Ada `and then`. Likewise Python `or`, Ada `or else`.